# Prove that $\int \limits _{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2x}-e^{-ax}}{x}\text{d}x$ converges for any $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I'm doing this exercise:

> Prove that $F(a)=\displaystyle\int \limits _{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2x}-e^{-ax}}{x}\text{d}x$ converges for every $a>0$. Calculate $F'(a)$ and deduce $F(a)$.

I've separated the integral in 
$$F(a)=\displaystyle\int \limits _{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2x}-e^{-ax}}{x}\text{d}x=\displaystyle\int \limits _{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2x}}{x}\text{d}x-\displaystyle\int \limits _{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}}{x}\text{d}x$$
and I've tried to identify them with the gamma function, but $\Gamma(0)$ does not exist.

Edit: To decide whether it's convergent or not, can I use Dirichlet's test?

Any hint would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think we have a sign problem, the integral does not converge.  Don't need Maple, $e^{ax}$ blows up real bad.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks, Maple says so too, I'm going to change the question.

Comment: To investigate convergence you only need to study two things $x=0$ and the growth as $x\to \infty$. For $x=0$ Taylor expand to see that the integrand has a finite limit here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $F'(a) = \int \limits _0 ^\infty \Bbb e ^{-ax} \Bbb d x = \dfrac {e ^{-ax}} {-a} \bigg| _0 ^\infty = \dfrac 1 a$, which implies $F(a) = \ln a + C$ where $C$ is a constant that we must find out. In order to do this, evaluate $F$ in $a=2$: on the one hand, this must be $0$; on the other hand, it is $\ln 2 + C$, so $C = - \ln 2$, which implies $F(a) = \ln \dfrac a 2$.

Comment: How did you find $F'(a)$?

Comment: The derivative with respect to $a$ "slips inside" the integral, so you only have to derive (with respect to $a$) the integrand $\dfrac {\Bbb e ^{-2x} - \Bbb e ^{-ax}} {x}$.