# Calculate the integral $ F(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2x}-e^{ax}}{x} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Calculate the integral $ F(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2x}-e^{ax}}{x}  dx$, where $a>0$. 
And what about $F'(a)?$

Please I need help with this integral.

Comment: Duplication of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566194/prove-that-int-limits-0-infty-frace-2x-e-axx-textdx-conver

Comment: Duplicate, including the typo that was discussed in the original question. It should be $-a$, otherwise the function isn't integrable.

Comment: This is an example of [Frullani's Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hint : you could use the fact that $e^{-2x}-e^{ax} = e^{-2x}-1-(e^{ax}-1)$ and $e^x = \sum_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Answer (score -1):

Use Frullani integral.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x}=(f(0)-f(\infty)))\cdot ln\left ( \frac{b}{a} \right )
$$